# Is it possible to cascade none in hibernate spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate and Spring,

I have an object `Course` and object `User`.

So, the logic is the admin can create a course using an existing user and
the existing user will already have an existing role.

My repository class for the `Course` object extends `CrudRepository`.
To save the course object, I use

```java
courseRepository.save(course);
```

But I have an issue with the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.example.project.model.Course.user -> com.example.project.model.User
```

I am not sure how to not save the `User` and `Role` object which already exists in the database. I tried to use `CascadeType.None` but I can't find the import/ dependency. Currently, it keeps forcing me to save into the database the user and role object which causes duplicate data.

Course class :

```java
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long course_id;
    private String course_name;
    private String course_desc;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {})
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;

    //setter & getter
}
```

User class:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String identificationNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {})
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    private Role role;
}
```

Role class:

```java
@Entity
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    private long role_id;
    private String role_name;
    private String role_desc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how to not save the User and Role object which already exists in the database.

You can obtain an entity reference without initializing its data by calling [EntityManager.getReference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference) in the following way:

```java
Course course = new Course();
course.setUser( entityManager.getReference( User.class, userId) );
// ...
courseRepository.save(course);
```